# I'm seeing red dots everywhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, top-bar

On all Stack Exchange sites where I have review privileges, the review queue menu icon has a red dot. No matter what I try, it doesn't go away.

[image]

[This bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360628/4751173) on Meta Stack Overflow might or might not be related.

Comment: can confirm it has just started happening for me as well

Comment: I thought it was a Christmas bauble: part of the winter bash snowflake.

Comment: Yup. It's happening on all the sites. Beat me by a minute. I was just about to click post.

Comment: Definitely related to the MSO report, same issue there. I linked your post over there.

Comment: Question asked at the same time with screen shot showing empty queue here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304438/162102

Comment: Confirmed. Fix is going out now.

Comment: Was just coming to post the same question ;)

Comment: I thought it was somehow related to Rudolph :( thanks for killing the magic

Comment: Related: [Experiment: Review-needed indicator logic for sites that sometimes have empty queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/1438).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be fixed now. It was related to some changes we made to an upcoming feature we've been working on. Stay tuned!

Comment: Oops! Red dots for everyone, always.

Comment: Hats for everyone as compensation! :-D

Comment: This is still an issue, at least for me on sustainability.se...

Comment: @JonChan This issue/bug is random and recurring for us at JSX: https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/333/12352