# Review alert is over-eager

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

I'm seeing the red alert on sites where there's nothing to review:

[image: Community Building]

That's from Community Building, where I'm pretty sure the queues are empty.  I also just saw it on Worldbuilding meta, where I'm a moderator and also see nothing special (like pending VLQ/NAA flags).

And it's sticking around after I close the dialogue.  Visiting one of the review queues from the drop-down didn't dismiss it either.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think you both asked it at the same time. Which one is the duplicate? :)

Comment: Yeah, look at those timestamps.  I searched and checked the front page before asking and didn't find yours.

Comment: Yeah, that happens when they break important stuff :)