# Notification icon colour has changed to dark red

Tags: support, design, notifications, top-bar

I noticed that the colour of notification icon has changed since 2 days.

This is how it looks like to me here on Meta.

[image: Image of top bar showing notification and achievements on Meta Stack Exchange]

Formerly, the notifications colour icon used to be brighter and eye catching like this.

[image: Image of top bar on Chat. Stack Exchange showing notifications and achievements]

The former colour was eye catching and brighter than the current one. The current one indicates (to me) that there is an urgent matter to handle like the review queues.

Is this the change due to the [experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/357396) going on with the review icon? I tend to think so because the red in the review icon and the red in the notification looks very much similar. Below is an image from Movies&TV Stack Exchange where I have access to review queues.

[image: Image of top bar on Movies &TV showing notification bar and review icon]

Is this due to the experiments on review icon? Is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it has. It's the same shade as the review icon red dot, incidentally. [Jon mentioned on chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6562917#6562917) that the designers asked about standardising on one shade of red, so presumably it's a way to get a more unified colour palette. And they went for the more muted red of the review icon over the brighter old notification red.

It's kinda growing on me actually. Presumably, you'd need a userscript, since from what I can tell, it's network wide.

Comment: Spot on. It was a bug that the bright red ever shipped.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this simply with a custom stylesheet:

```
.top-bar .indicator-badge._important {
    background-color: rgb(252, 13, 27);
}
```

It depends on the browser you're using how this works exactly, but there are a lot of extensions/plugins for this.