# Review Notification, but no Reviews?

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

I was on Worldbuilding today when I saw the notification symbol on the review button in the top bar.  I clicked on the button, and saw this:

[image: Review Popup open, but no reviews?]

This isn't the first time this has happened either.  I don't have any other screenshots, but I've seen this two or three times before (all on Worldbuilding).  Is this intended behaviour of some sort, or a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's intended but not optimal.

The indicator is only aware of what reviews exist, not which are available to you so if there are reviews you've completed or if you don't have access to all of the queues due to your reputation, you will see the indicator but not have anything to review (as far as I'm aware this hasn't been fixed yet). This is mentioned in [Jon Ericson's discussion about improving this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/experiment-review-needed-indicator-logic-for-sites-that-sometimes-have-empty-qu):

> One final thing: **you *will* be notified even when you cannot complete a review task** (for anyone who can see the review queue - 500+ reputation). In particular, people who do not have enough reputation to handle items all the queues will be notified of items in queues they can't access. This is the next thing we are working to fix.

So, in your case, they could be tag wiki suggested edits that you need 5k to review or it could just be that the items in the queues are waiting on more votes from other users. At the time of posting, there are three items in the close vote queue on Worldbuilding and you've already reviewed all three of them.

Fortunately (?) the indicator is cleared for an hour after you click on it, so you'll get a bit of a reprieve.

Comment: Thank-you for this alternative explanation.  Is 1201ProgramAlarm's answer also a possibility, or not?

Comment: It's *possible*... it probably depends on how active a site's review queues are. In this specific instance, since I still saw three items in the queue, I don't think it's the explanation for what you're experiencing.

Comment: Thank-you, Catija.  Kinda weird that there are three items in the tag wiki suggested edit queue, but whatever.

Comment: No, it's in the close vote queue. :)

Comment: Oh, I suppose I've already cleared those then (but they're still active for other users).  I'm still seeing nothing.

Comment: Yep. Exactly. Two of them have three votes to close and one has only two.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Catija (and congrats on your newish job).

Comment: Sometimes, I've been notified in the top bar of suggested edits, when the only edits waiting for review are *my own* tag wiki edits.

Answer (score 2):

The menu isn't populated until you open it up.  Between the time the top bar is loaded, and your action to open the menu, the status of the review queues changed enough for the notification to not show.