# Curse of the red blob (more than usual)

Tags: discussion, bug, review, notifications, top-bar

On the [biology stack](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions) I comparatively recently started performing basic reviews, the last two days (this being the third) the first-post review queue has contained a notification red-blob, and during this time I've done a couple of reviews. Mostly though, the red-blob has signified nothing at all, no reviews.

Nothing abnormal about that, review-notifications have always been laggy and misleading, as there may be reviews being undertaken by other users which prevents yours but not the red-blob from appearing - described as [intended but not optimal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314062/259608) in that meta post.

But for three days continually? (On a fairly quiet site without that many reviews going-on anyhow. If a user walks away from their computer half-way through a review, would that cause this?) Anyone seen this elsewhere?

Expected behaviour:

They should be erratic and show occasional presence of reviews which aren't there, then disappear within a few minutes until next time. There should also be occasional reviews.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305893/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296946/282094 
and in particular:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/282094

Comment: "False positives are certainly discouraging, so we'll want to eliminate as many as possible, if not all." Jon Ericson 2017. The good intentions are there if not the way to untangle the code, yet.

Comment: Re: *Anyone seen this elsewhere?* I'm a fairly active reviewer on LawSE, and my blob doesn't hang around for long - I've not timed it but I'd say no more than an hour at the most, and definitely not three days!

Comment: It's business as usual on the other sites I review on too, just biology showing itself up. @Rick

Comment: It will likely be lit all the time, [with 50+ in the queues](https://biology.stackexchange.com/reviews). One request for [no false alarms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302608/282094) is more than a few years old, with a [newer one June 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798/282094); the newest being the one in your question. --- There's no "duplicate", because it's fair to re-ask.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're talking about the red blob of a specific queue?

Comment: Don't believe that I forgot to mention it, the first questions queue I mean. I had a bad picture, discarded it, forgot to snap another. @Joachim

Comment: ARogueAnt, need images?, The [Data Science queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlcHR.png) correctly shows a red dot, but the [Video Production queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4foPM.png) has no red dot even though no one has done a review today. --- Be certain that your question applies to more than one site (it does) or it can be closed and migrated to your meta; we only accept multi-site bug reports and feature requests.